# Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES with another table with more TABLE_NAMES and result would be different if table name is in the first table or not

Tags: sql-server, left-join, information-schema

we have a Table with a list of table names we want to be created. They don't have an ID column or anything, it's just a few rows of data with 2 columns. Thing is we want to merge that table with **Information_schema.table** to check which of the tables we have already created and which we have not, so we wrote the query below as a temp to achieve such:

```
with cte1 as (
select d.TABNAME, d.CLASS from dbo.table_list as d
left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as t on t.TABLE_NAME = d.TABNAME
where d.CLASS in ('INIT','STERN') and table_schema = 'dbo'),

cte2 as (select d.TABNAME, d.CLASS
from dbo.table_list as d
where d.CLASS in ('INIT','TERN') and d.TABNAME not in (select [TABLE NAME] from cte1))


select *, 'Active' as [Status] from cte1 union all
select * , 'Inactive' from cte2
```

This is what table_list looks like:

| TABNAME | CLASS |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE1 | INIT |
| TABLE2 | STERN |
| TABLE3 | STERN |
| TABLE4 | STERN |
| TABLE5 | INIT |

We already have TABLE1 and TABLE2 created so the result of the query looks like this:

| TABNAME | CLASS | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE1 | INIT | Active |
| TABLE2 | STERN | Active |
| TABLE3 | STERN | Inactive |
| TABLE4 | STERN | Inactive |
| TABLE5 | INIT | Inactive |

It works well enough like this but we were wondering if we could make it shorter.

Comment: The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are left for backwards compatibility. They are also not always correct. In particular the schema can be wrong, it is even stated in the documentation that they may be incorrect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @SeanLange, I wouldn't say the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are left for backwards compatibility but that they are needed to comply with ISO SQL standards. The SQL Server meta-data catalog views and functions are much more robust so I suggest one use those unless cross-DBMS code is desired, which is a pipe dream IMHO.

Comment: @DanGuzman good clarification and correction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be *way* shorter, yes. You could just reference the table `dbo.table_list` and see if you get a valid `OBJECT_ID`:

```sql
SELECT tl.TABNAME,
       tl.CLASS,
       CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.' + QUOTENAME(tl.TABNAME)) IS NULL THEN 'Inactive' ELSE 'Active' END AS Status
FROM dbo.table_list tl --"d" for "table_list" doesn't make a lot of sense.
WHERE tl.CLASS IN ('INIT','STERN');
```

If you wanted to use the catalog views, you could use `CROSS APPLY` to join to the table while supplying a value for both the schema and table name, or just `JOIN` to `sys.schemas` based on a literal and then `LEFT JOIN` to `sys.tables`:

```sql
SELECT tl.TABNAME,
       tl.CLASS,
       CASE WHEN st.[name] IS NULL THEN 'Inactive' ELSE 'Active' END AS Status
FROM dbo.table_list tl --"d" for "table_list" doesn't make a lot of sense.
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.[name]
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                  WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo'
                    AND t.[name] = tl.TABNAME) st
WHERE tl.CLASS IN ('INIT','STERN');

SELECT tl.TABNAME,
       tl.CLASS,
       CASE WHEN t.[name] IS NULL THEN 'Inactive' ELSE 'Active' END AS Status
FROM dbo.table_list tl --"d" for "table_list" doesn't make a lot of sense.
     JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.[name] = N'dbo'
     LEFT JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                           AND tl.TABNAME = t.[name]
WHERE tl.CLASS IN ('INIT','STERN');
```